# Automatize regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a panel named df with different rounds, round == 0 being baseline and round == 11 being endline. I want to automatize the regression by specifying the outcome (y), the baseline control (outcome in round == 11) and the mean of the baseline control. But I'm having trouble with how to set the outcome and the expression it should be in. I'm worried as well by the different NAs in the different rounds. My code so far:

```
outcome <- "ps_depression_cesd"
baseline_control <- filter(df$outcome, round == 11)
mean_control <- mean(baseline_control, na.rm = T) 

reg_1  <- felm(outcome ~ treatment
                   | level1 + round_cont | 0 | level4 + hhid, data = df)

reg_2  <- felm(outcome ~ treatment + baseline_control + mean_control
                   | level1 + round_cont | 0 | level4 + hhid, data = df)

reg_3 <- felm(outcome ~ treat_uct + treat_ffa 
                   | level1 + round_cont | 0 | level4 + hhid, data = df)

reg_4  <- felm(outcome ~ treat_uct + treat_ffa + baseline_control + mean_control
                   | level1 + round_cont | 0 | level4 + hhid, data = df)
```

Comment: hi Paula! Would you be able to include a small reproducible data sample? dput() is handy with this

Comment: what does `stargzer` or `tidyverse` have to do with your question?  What is the question - are you trying to loop through different models?